# Растягиваются объекты вдали от центра

Tags: javascript, webgl, jstree

Имеется такой код:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>MDN Games: Three.js demo</title>
 <style>
  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script>
 var bgColor = 0xf0f1f2;
 var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
 var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
 //renderer
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 renderer.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
 renderer.setClearColor(bgColor);//renderer.setClearColor(bgColor, 1);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 //scene
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();
 //camera
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, screenWidth/screenHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); //new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH/HEIGHT);
 camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
 camera.up.set(0, 0, 0);
 camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
 scene.add(camera);
 
 //Object
 var group = new THREE.Object3D();
 
 
 var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
 
 function clickOnDot(event)
 {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055214/mouse-canvas-x-y-to-three-js-world-x-y-z/49847108#49847108
  // Mouse / Canvas X, Y to Three.js World X, Y, Z
  //
  // get x,y coords into canvas where click occurred
  var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  // convert x,y to clip space; coords from top left, clockwise:
  // (-1,1), (1,1), (-1,-1), (1, -1)
  var worldCoordMouse = new THREE.Vector3();
  worldCoordMouse.x = ( (x / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2) - 1;
  worldCoordMouse.y = (-(y / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2) + 1;
  worldCoordMouse.z = 0.5; // set to z position of mesh objects
  // reverse projection from 3D to screen
  worldCoordMouse.unproject(camera);
  // convert from point to a direction
  worldCoordMouse.sub(camera.position).normalize();
  // scale the projected ray
  var distance = -camera.position.z / worldCoordMouse.z;
  var scaled = worldCoordMouse.multiplyScalar(distance);
  var worldCoords = camera.position.clone().add(scaled);
 
 
  //console.log("Click screen coord: " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);  
  //console.log("Click world coord: " + worldCoords.x + ", " + worldCoords.y);   
 
  // 
  // Intersection
  //
  var screenCoordMouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  screenCoordMouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  screenCoordMouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1; 
  raycaster.setFromCamera( screenCoordMouse, camera );   
 
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children  , true);
 
  //intersects.forEach(function(element){
  // console.log("Intersection: " + element.object.id);
  //});

  CreateDot(worldCoords.x, worldCoords.y, worldCoords.z);
 }
 
 function CreateDot(posX, posY)
 {
  var geometory = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.5,6,6);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x1a1a1a });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometory, material);
  mesh.position.x = posX;
  mesh.position.y = posY;
  mesh.position.z = 0;
  group.add(mesh);
  scene.add(group);
 }
 
 
 
 function render() 
 {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'click', clickOnDot, false );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
 }
render();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Данная программа по нажатию клавиши лкм добавляет точки. Проблема в том, что точка выглядит круглой только в центре экрана, а по бокам она похожа на эллипс. Это из за того, что точкой является сфера. Как сделать, что бы точки были везде и всегда круглые и одного размера?

Comment: Использовать ортографическую проекцию?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ решилось все намного проще, вместо сфер стал добавлять круги) P.S. Может знаете как совмещать прямые линии и кривые Безье?)